Cant' delete files/directories on Synology
I'm on macOS 14.4.1 and have Emacs 29.2 plus installed from Homebrew.
I have an access problem with Dired on my Synology when I try to delete files: "file-error: Removing old name: Operation not permitted." copying to the Synology works, as well as creating new files and folders.
In the past, I accessed my Synology via SSH and TRAMP, but Synology introduced an upgrade at some point that made this a bit more involved/complex, and I am now mounting my Synology shares with the macOS system using SMB, and then I navigate to those using Dired. Emacs then sees this as a directory on /Volumes, not using TRAMP at all, and I think that might be the issue.
When I try to access SMB and TRAMP, I get "File not found and directory write-protected" from Emacs.
The way I connect with SMB via TRAMP (which works on Windows and Mac for me with full access) is: smb:[user]@[IP]. I might have it too simple; I don't get prompted for a password when I do that.
Does anyone connect to their Synology with Emacs, and if so, how? Do you have any access issues?

I have a QNAP system, which I access with both ssh and smb via Emacs/Tramp. When I access via smb, I need also to use the domain name. Something like /smb:user%domain@host:
